# Obviousness in methods

Tags: us5745902

To illustrate my question: Suppose there's prior art consisting of a nut and bolt, including the fact that when the nut is on the bolt, it holds together two things threaded onto the bolt, between the bolt head and the nut.

Now someone comes along seeking to patent a method that consists of threading the bolt into a hole in two objects and screwing the nut onto the other end of the bolt, so as to hold the objects together.

I'm trying to show that the method is obvious to someone skilled in the art, but there's no actual prior art that describes the method - no one thought to mention it, perhaps because they thought it was obvious, and their patent attorney wasn't on the ball.

It is obvious in a patent sense? Just how directly does the prior art have to apply to a method to invalidate claims on the method?

Edit: To put this in more concrete terms, what I have in the documentation of the prior art is a field in software that specifies how much space is allocated to a file. Presumably, when the prior-art software increased the amount of space allocated to a file, it updated the field to reflect that but I don't have the software to look at, and the documentation doesn't actually say that. A software engineer would say "Well, duh, of course the field has to be updated", but a patent examiner might take a different view.

The method being patented includes a claim with elements consisting of allocating more space to the file, and updating the field.

I want to be able to argue that the prior-art documentation I have covers updating the field, on the grounds that updating the field is obvious to a person skilled in the art, even though the prior-art doesn't specify a method.

Comment: If the technique is in use as a standard industry practice, it would no longer be patent eligible.

Comment: You make a good point. Patent examiners tend to focus on other patents for prior art. This has been a problem with software patents where prior art might instead be text books.

Comment: @DukeZhou I've edited the original question to provide a more concrete example.

Comment: What is your aim with this? Or to put it another way, who do you want to convince that a given claim is obvious? I ask because the obviousness standard is really quite subjective, and the only way to be confident on whether a claim is obvious is to have a court rule that it is obvious. Without this, the best you could get to is "probably obvious".

Comment: @Maca I need to convince the USPTO, so that they'll invalidate the patent.

Comment: Has the patent already been granted? Anyways, the bolt example is not obvious (as eric says). Now towards your problem - one way would be getting experts to testify, another way would be to find any form of written source hinting this or describing it. Thats a lot of work, which is why patent invalidation costs a lot of money ;). Another way would be trying to separate the software part from the hardware part in the argumentation, but I am not sure how this works in the US. At the EPO you would have a good shot arguing that the pure software implementation does not count for inventiveness.

Comment: Another possibility is to simply ask for a license. If this is a narrow application and doesn't fundamentally challenge the assignee's business, they may be willing to license for a reasonable fee. This may be much cheaper than trying to invalidate an existing patent (for both parties).

Comment: The patent is one of a set that support Microsoft's claims to the exFat filesystem. Licenses are available, but they cost money. I'm trying to invalidate them so that exFat can be supported in distributions of Linux.

Comment: Time to contact www.eff.org.

Answer (score 1):

You question is interesting and I think you understand the idea of obviousness relating to someone skilled skilled in the art. I'll defer to the patent lawyers who lurk here to weigh in on the subtleties of obviousness.

Your example however, is not quite as obvious as you assume. Of course, threaded fasteners have been around hundred(s) of years, but the example you cite sort of describes the use of a jam nut. It turns out using a jam nut rather than a simple bolt/nut connection can greatly increase the resistance of a threaded fastener to loosening due to vibration. As I said this is well known in mechanical engineering, but someone must have been the first person to figure it out and I'm assuming when they did, they could have patented the idea.